# How to install the dns-sd command line test tool on Windows or Linux?

Tags: networking, bonjour, service-discovery, zeroconf, dns-sd

The book *Zero Configuration Networking - The Definite Guide* by Stuart Cheshire and Daniel H. Steinberg from 2005 describes a *dns-sd* command line test tool which should be available for macOS, Windows and Linux. At the beginning of chapter 6 (p. 92) he describes the tool, but it's not an explicit guide on how to download and install it, just that is available from the Darwin open source repository.

The tool offers commands like `dns-sd -B` which browses for service instances.

I'm a Windows and Linux user, but have problems to find the tool. Bonjour is already installed on my Windows system, but it's not clear to me if this is enough or if I need to download the tool explicitly. When I type `dns-sd` on the windows command line, it says this command is unknown. How to make it available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I just found the out how it works on Windows and now I can answer my question by myself. Not sure how it work on Linux yet.

On Windows, you can install the Bonjour SDK which is downloadable at [developer.apple.com/opensource/](https://developer.apple.com/opensource/), click on `Command Line Tools` and search for `dns-sd` or `bonjour sdk`.

After the installation wizard successfully finished its job, you can go directly to your command line, type in `dns-sd` and you'll get a list of all possible commands. No further comfinguration needed. *Tested on Windows 10.*

Comment: **Avahi** implements dns-sd in Linux. It provides a bunch of command-line tools to publish and discover services. You can find more details here: https://www.avahi.org/

Comment: The link doesn't contain anything about dns-sd (anymore?).