# Flutter/Multicast DNS: How to test network discovery with MDNS

Tags: flutter, dns, network-programming, service-discovery, mdns

I have implemented network discovery with **MDNS** for my Flutter mobile app using the [multicast_dns](https://pub.dev/packages/multicast_dns/example) package.

The idea behind this was that the mobile app should **automatically detect the server address on the local network**. MDNS seems to be the more elegant approach instead of port scanning the entire local network.

The code looks something like this:

```dart
final MDnsClient client = MDnsClient(rawDatagramSocketFactory: factory);

const String name = '_http._tcp';
await client.start();
// Get the PTR recod for the service.
await for (PtrResourceRecord ptr in client
    .lookup<PtrResourceRecord>(ResourceRecordQuery.serverPointer(name))) {

  // Use the domainName from the PTR record to get the SRV record,
  // which will have the port and local hostname.
  // Note that duplicate messages may come through, especially if any
  // other mDNS queries are running elsewhere on the machine.
  await for (SrvResourceRecord srv in client.lookup<SrvResourceRecord>(
  ResourceRecordQuery.service(ptr.domainName))) {
      final String bundleId =
      ptr.domainName; //.substring(0, ptr.domainName.indexOf('@'));
      print('http server instance found at '
      '${srv.target}:${srv.port} for "$bundleId".');
  }
}
client.stop();
```

Now, I am searching for a way to **mock said service with MDNS** because the server isn't actually ready yet.

I have found something like this for this for MACOS:

```
dns-sd -R TestService _http._tcp . 3000
```

However, I found nothing like this for **Windows** (or Linux). How do I advertize/mock a http service per DNS in order to test my network discovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219036/1987437) to get the same tool, `dns-sd` running on windows.

Personally, I would just make a quick program in Go using the `mdns` [package](https://github.com/hashicorp/mdns/tree/v1.0.5) that I could compile to any OS I wanted.

Either way works.

Comment: I ended up installing `dns_sd` on windows. Worked perfectly as described.